# Submit button isn't working on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i'm having an issue with IE9, I have a form like this:

```
<form action="" class="new-form form-insc-widg">
<input type="hidden" name="tipo" tal:attributes="value item/tipo">
<input type="hidden" name="data">
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="input-nameil cs-input">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="input-nameil cs-input">
<tal:block tal:condition="python: item['tipo'] == 'fed'">
  <select name="federacao" class="custom-chosen-js" id="sel-federations">
    <option value="">Selecione uma federação</option>
    <option>FIEA</option>
    <option>FIEAC</option>
    <option>FIEAM</option>
    <option>FIEAP</option>
    <option>FIEB</option>
    <option>FIEC</option>
    <option>FIBRA</option>
    <option>FINDES</option>
    <option>FIEG</option>
    <option>FIEMA</option>
    <option>FIEMG</option>
    <option>FIEMS</option>
    <option>FIEMT</option>
    <option>FIEPA</option>
    <option>FIEP - PB</option>
    <option>FIEPE</option>
    <option>FIEPI</option>
    <option>FIEP - PR</option>
    <option>FIRJAN</option>
    <option>FIERN</option>
    <option>FIERO</option>
    <option>FIER</option>
    <option>FIERGS</option>
    <option>FIES</option>
    <option>FIESC</option>
    <option>FIESP</option>
    <option>FIETO</option>
  </select>
</tal:block>
<tal:block tal:condition="python: item['tipo'] == 'sin'">
  <div class="sind-controls">
    <select name="uf" class="custom-chosen-js" id="">
      <option value="">UF</option>
      <option>AL</option>
      <option>AC</option>
      <option>AM</option>
      <option>AP</option>
      <option>BA</option>
      <option>CE</option>
      <option>DF</option>
      <option>ES</option>
      <option>GO</option>
      <option>MA</option>
      <option>MG</option>
      <option>MS</option>
      <option>MT</option>
      <option>PA</option>
      <option>PB</option>
      <option>PE</option>
      <option>PI</option>
      <option>PR</option>
      <option>RJ</option>
      <option>RN</option>
      <option>RO</option>
      <option>RR</option>
      <option>RS</option>
      <option>SE</option>
      <option>SC</option>
      <option>SP</option>
      <option>TO</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="cs-input" name="link" placeholder="Link do site" id="">
  </div>
</tal:block>
<button class="gradient botao-do-selecionar" type="submit">Continue</button>
```

When I click on "Continue" button with other browsers, it is opening a modal (that's what I want) but when I click in that button with any versions of IE, it seems to do nothing, no erros, no network traffic... Anyone has an ideia of what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code which opens the modal?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap classes to open the modal...

Answer (score 0):

Try it by changing `<button>` to `<input>`

```
<input class="gradient botao-do-selecionar" type="submit">Continue</input>
```